# Dirac delta normalization of electromagnetic fields

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-delta-distributions, second-quantization, normalization

Usually, to quantize electromagnetic fields we use box normalization and therefore the normalization constant contains the dimensions of Volume V of the box.

But if we perform the Dirac-delta normalization for a free field, I am finding the difficulty to understand how is the dimension of the volume taken into account so that the dimensions of electric field does not change.

It would be really helpful if someone could answer my query and suggest some literature where I could read more about it.

Comment: The dimensions of the Dirac delta are 1/Arg

Answer (score 0):

$$
[\delta^3(x)]=[L^{-3}]
$$
and more generally
$$
[\delta^D(x)]=[L^{-D}]
$$
being $D$ the dimensions of the space.